# Excel: How to make the Home tab "stay put"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, tabs, display-settings

This is a new problem (have not experienced it before; am running Excel 2010).

The workbook opens with the File tab active.
So I switch to the Home tab to do some editing.
The problem is that after just one edit (such as changing the color of a cell), the File tab becomes the active tab again. So to continue with editing, I have to switch back to the Home tab.

I thought maybe there was Display setting that needed to be checked in (or out), but as best I can tell, there's no option controlling active/inactive tabs.

How do I make the Home tab stay active with having to repeatedly switch back to it?

Comment: Yes, I was hasty in typing. I've edited my original post. Based on tangential research I've done, the problem is not necessarily unique to 2010, and can also happen with other Office products such as Outlook..

Comment: that's fine. Even in the case a question applies to multiple versions, it's best to indicate the version *you* have. Good answers will indicate what versions they apply to if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me.

1. Go to Home tab and right click to show the toolbar options.
2. Disable (uncheck) the minimize ribbon button.

Comment: Thank you RJo! Having to constantly switch from File to Home was driving me nuts!

Comment: So glad to be able to spare others MS Office pain whenever possible.

Comment: Typical microsoft office, everything is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Home tab and right click to show the toolbar options. already enable  minimize ribbon button. Just click one time minimize ribbon button. problem fixed

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1171032)